# How do I get access to images and diagrams during the private pilot knowledge test?

Tags: usa, student-pilot

I am not sure if the testing center is online or paper based. However, on the private pilot knowledge test, how would one manage the questions related to density altitude, ground roll distance etc., when the images are on the computer and one has to use a paper/ ruler to get the right answer.

Are we allowed to take the print outs from the following website to the exam?

https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/supplements/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The testing center provides a physical, paper booklet with all the diagrams, pictures, charts etc. needed for the questions. You can't write on it (well, you can but you shouldn't!) however you can certainly use a ruler or paper edge as you mentioned. The test itself is online.

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed to take plotters, certain calculators, and E6-Bs into the test. Details are at p 3-5 and 3-6 [Order 8080.6H](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_8080.6H.pdf) There are some restrictions on the types of calculator. The aviation-specific ones sold by places like Sporty’s and ASA are OK. Fancy ones that can store programs are not.

> b. Test Materials. Applicants may use scales, straightedges,
> protractors, plotters, navigation computers, blank logsheets, holding
> pattern entry aids, and electronic or mechanical calculators that are
> directly related to the test.
>
> c. Manufacturers’ Aids. Manufacturers’ permanently inscribed
> instructions on the front and back of such aids (e.g., formulas,
> conversions, regulations, signals, weather data, holding pattern
> diagrams, frequencies, Weight and Balance (W&B) formulas, and air
> traffic control (ATC) procedures) are permissible.